# Multiple VMs from Terraform on vsphere

Tags: terraform, vsphere, terraform-template-file

I am trying to provision multiple vms with a single resource. My network IP is a CAM variable. It is a list of two IP Addresses.

How can I use the IP address list in the resource?

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "node01_fs" {
   count="2"
   name             = "${var.node01-name}${count.index +1}"
   folder           = "${var.Vsphere_folder}"
   num_cpus         = "${var.node01_number_of_vcpu}"
   memory           = "${var.node01_memory}"
   resource_pool_id ="${data.vsphere_resource_pool.node01_resource_pool.id}"
   datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.node01_datastore.id}"
   guest_id         ="${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.node01_template.guest_id}"
   scsi_type        = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.node01_template.scsi_type}"

   clone {
        template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.node01_template.id}"

  customize {
      linux_options {
          domain    = "${var.node01_domain}${count.index +1}"
          host_name = "${var.node01-name}${count.index +1}"
      }

   network_interface {
       ipv4_address = "${var.node01_ipv4_address[count]}"
       ipv4_netmask = "${var.node01_ipv4_prefix_length}"
    }

    ipv4_gateway    = "${var.node01_ipv4_gateway}"
    dns_suffix_list = "${var.node01_dns_suffixes}"
    dns_server_list = "${var.node01_dns_servers}"
  }
}

disk {
  label          = "${var.node01-name}${count.index +1}.disk0"
  size           = "${var.node01_root_disk_size}"
  keep_on_remove = "${var.node01_root_disk_keep_on_remove}"
}
```

I get this error when

> Error: variable node01_ipv4_address should be type string, got list

Comment: Where is the variable declaration for `node01_ipv4_address` and what are you passing to it?

Comment: On the varibale declaration part i was missing the type 'list'. Now the problem is fixed.